# Why are there no covariant particles?

Tags: particle-physics, metric-tensor, field-theory, tensor-calculus, standard-model

Why is physics described by scalar, spinor, vector, and tensor bundles, but not convector bundles or tensors of other ranks? In tensor bundle notation, these are respectively $T_0^0, S, T_0^1, T_0^2$. I am referring to the fields associated with the fundamental particles. Why are there no (1,1)-tensor particles or (0,1)-particles? Why do particles not have a covariant part?

Comment: Because if you have a metric, they're isomorphic.

Comment: To be fair, the photon and gluons are rather described by one-form fields, not by vectors.